# Redis full search text with C#

Tags: c#, redis, full-text-search

Is there any way to do full-text search on Redis with C#?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/redis/nredisstack

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see http://playnice.ly/blog/2010/05/05/a-fast-fuzzy-full-text-index-using-redis/.

The code is about 100 LOC in Python, and can be transformed to C#.

The code uses `metaphone` Python library; you can find C# implementations online, such as this one: http://code.google.com/p/doublemetaphone/

Answer (score 1):

[RediSearch](http://redisearch.io) implements a search engine on top of Redis.
This also enables more advanced features, like exact phrase matching and numeric filtering for text queries, that are not possible or efficient with traditional Redis search approaches.

RediSearch supports the most of the leading programming languages including C# see: https://libraries.io/nuget/NRediSearch